# Is $g$ equal to $g'$: injective and surjective?

Tags: functions

So the problem says that $f: X \to Y, g: Y \to Z$, and $g': Y \to Z$ are functions.

Prove that
$g\circ f = g'\circ f$ being that $f$ is surjective, then $g= g'$.

So I understand that $f(x) = y,\ g(y) = z$, and $g'(y) =z$.

So $f$ is surjective, which only means that for every $y$ there is some $x$ that leads to it, but that doesn't mean that two $x$'s could not equal the same $y$ (like an injective function would)

So could I just start by saying that we assume $g$ and $g'$ are different functions
where

$g(y) = \sin (y)$  and $g'(y) = \cos (y)$ 
and that

$f(x) = 3$ 
then I can show that

$g(f(x) = y = 3) = \sin 3 $

$g'(f(x) = y = 3) = \cos 3$

this would then go against the statement that $g\circ f = g'\circ f$, which means that $g$ and $g'$ have to be the same function in order for $g\circ f = g'\circ f$ to be true. So proof by contradiction. Is this along the same route I should take or am I completely off?

Comment: You assumed some things that made the problem way too specific. If $f$ is surjective and $f(x)$ is identically $3$, then you've implicitly assumed that $Y = \{3\}$. You also shouldn't use specific functions for $g$ and $g'$. Use only the info they gave.

Answer (score 3):

Let $y\in Y$ be arbitrary. Since $f$ is surjective, there is some $x\in X$ such that $y=f(x)$. But
$$g(y)=g(f(x))=gof (x)=g'of(x)=g'(f(x))=g'(y)$$
Since $y$ is arbitrarily chosen, $g=g'$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use "specific" functions for $f,g,g'$ unless you are trying to disprove the assertion (not the same thing as a proof by contradiction).

A proof by contradiction would go as follows:

Suppose $g \circ f = g' \circ f$, and that $f$ is surjective, but $g \neq g'$.

This means there is at least one $y \in Y$, with $g(y) \neq g'(y)$.

Since $f$ is surjective, we have some $x \in X$ with $f(x) = y$.

Because $g \circ f = g' \circ f$, we know that:

$(g \circ f)(x) = (g' \circ f)(x)$, that is:

$g(f(x)) = g'(f(x)) \implies g(y) = g'(y)$, contradiction.